# return value of setcookie() in php

Tags: php

According to phpmanual http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php If output exists prior to calling this function, setcookie() will fail and return FALSE.

```
<?php
echo "fail";
echo setcookie("stack", "overflow")? "pass" : "fail";
```

it should output failfail as I've output something earlier than setcookie() in the script.

Unfortunately it outputs failpass.

Why?

Comment: Because the cookie got set?! Only 1 parameter is needed according from the manual

Comment: @Rizier123 That's his question: why is it setting the cookie when the manual says it shouldn't?

Comment: Typically, output is buffered to a degree by webservers, rather than sent byte by byte as you echo it; so it may be a case that such a small output as "fail" has not yet been sent to a browser, so the server is still capable of sending headers before output

Comment: PHP could be buffering the output by default, check for example the value of `output_buffering` in your php.ini file.

Comment: So based on what @MarkBaker has said - do _not_ rely on this behavior.  Never attempt to call `setcookie(),session_start(),header()` after output of any kind has occurred unless you are controlling output buffering (but even that's often a hack)

Comment: @Barmar it isn't - I misread

Comment: Surely echoing out a large amount of data prior to the setcookie call will confirm/deny that buffering is happening? Give it a shot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output of the script is cached using a [small buffer](http://php.net/manual/en/outcontrol.configuration.php) (4 KiB by default). This allows tricks like the one exposed by your question, when the script sends some headers after it outputs a small amount of text.

Check your `php.ini` for the `output_buffering` setting.

Answer (score 0):

////solved////
output_buffering was On by default in php.ini
I set it to off 
now it outputs failfail

thanks jeroen